# Add model predictions as a column in pandas but keep NaN as prediction if null values present in the row

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has some null values and want to add a new column `model_prediction` which is model's predictions on the data.
The model I have does not take null values and I want the `model_prediction` value to be NaN for those rows. The problem is the dataframe is very large and using df.iterrows is a very slow process and want to avoid it.

Comment: please paste some sample data along with desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is `df` and model is `model`, please try this:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df_na = df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
df_na.loc[:,'model_prediction'] = np.nan
df_model = df.dropna()
df_model.loc[:,'model_prediction'] = model.predict(df_model.values)
df = df_model.append(df_na).sort_index()
```

Comment: Does the order of the rows change because of this? I don't want to change the order

Comment: No, it won't change the order. But please do check and confirm. If you post any sample dataset, I can also check